# Print matrix with one for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, line

I'm newbie to c#.

I have 2 variables which I get from user named "line" and "column". My goal is write "*" to screen about much lines and columns that I get from user. For example, user entered 5 column and 5 lines:

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

But when I run my program, It looks like:

```
00000
00000
00000
00000
0000
```

(yeah, the last one is missed).

My code is :

```
int i;
int satir, sutun;
Console.WriteLine("Kaç satır olsun?");
satir = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Kaç sütun olsun peki?");
sutun = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (i=1; i < sutun * satir; i++)
{
    if (i%sutun==0)
    {
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advice.

Comment: Debug it. Set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the output looks like this:

```
Kaç satır olsun?
5
Kaç sütun olsun peki?
5
****
****
****
****
****
```

I.e. instead of five columns you get four columns. For the first four lines it's because you are writing out a line break instead of the fifth asterisk, and for the last line it's because you are writing out one too few asterisks.

You should write out one more asterisk, which you can do by using the `<=` operator instead of `<` in the loop, and you shouldn't write out a line break *instead* of the asterisk, but after:

```
int i;
int satir, sutun;
Console.WriteLine("Kaç satır olsun?");
satir = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Kaç sütun olsun peki?");
sutun = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

for (i = 1; i <= sutun * satir; i++) {
  Console.Write("*");
  if (i % sutun == 0) {
    Console.Write("\n");
  }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` should be less than or equals to `sutun`.

```
for (i=1; i <= sutun * satir; i++)
```

**Bonus Note: How to debug my C# code**

Set a breakpoint in side your loop and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to go line by line. Then you can find out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Not only should your `for` loop look like (Changed `<` to `<=`):

```
for (i=1; i <= sutun * satir; i++)
```

You should print the asterisk no matter what.  Take the `Console.Write("*")` out of the `if/else` block and place it at the top of the loop, leaving only and `if` statement to print the `newline` character

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int i;
        int satir, sutun;
        Console.WriteLine("Kaç satır olsun?");
        satir = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Kaç sütun olsun peki?");
        sutun = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (i = 1; i <= sutun * satir; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            if (i % sutun == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Kaç satır olsun?
3
Kaç sütun olsun peki?
5
*****
*****
*****
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PKlLFc)